# Making an exception to stock quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Right now, I am bringing users to a Contact 7 Form, and adding to cart using the href link, http://example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=1000

I have a unique case where if there is 1 item left of product 1000, and the user chooses 2 in the dropdown box, then I should increase product 1000's quantity by 2 and allow the user to checkout normal.

I have looked at the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` and `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hooks, but couldn't figure it out.

I just need to understand, how I can make the modification before the user is directed to the checkout page and are not shown the "You cannot add that amount to the cart" message.

Comment: Kindly, your question is really **not clear** and understandable actually (try to reword it and clarify the context)… Also you should provide at least one of your code attempts in your question, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity', 'hook_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity', 'hook_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
function hook_get_stock_quantity( $value, $product ) {
    if($value < 2) $value = 10;
    return $value;
}
```